# JQuery Table Too Big For Page Solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I am using the jquery data tables plug in. My  table is too large for my page so I set scroll-x to true so my table is scrollable horizontally. Therefore even data that is hidden can be seen once scrolled over.

Does anybody have any efficient ideas of how to show a user that there is more data to the right? Right now all there is is a scroll bar that according to my users is not "sufficient". They do not believe that it is noticeable enough and could be missed.

Any ideas as far as icons, messages, etc that could be used to make the extra content more obvious? I'm sure people have had this problem before and I would love to hear some of your solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about using [Responsive](http://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/initialisation/option.html) extension to avoid horizontal scroll altogether? Your mobile visitors will thank you.

Comment: With this it seems like you lose columns.

Comment: I think this link would help you [http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/17013/best-way-to-display-more-table-columns-than-i-have-room-for](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/17013/best-way-to-display-more-table-columns-than-i-have-room-for)